# How to h-alignment subtable to the limits of text?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have this 2 subtables.
How could I separate more the 2 tables, puttin the space indicate in the image in the center to get bigger the central distance ?

I usually use \centering for center...  are there a similar command to h-align to right or left ?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}

jdhjfdks fjkf hjdshjds hfj kdhjk h dj fhdj  k  fhhfjdfd dsj fl k d sjf kd j fljkasdfk j sd alk  flka s j f kla sjf lkd sj fk l sajf kl dsj fl k d sjf kd j fljkasdfk j sd alk  flka s j f kla sjf lkd sj fk l sajf kl dsj fl k d sjf kd j fl
After a table we have.. THIS
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subtable}{.48\linewidth}
{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  {\scriptsize Tarea} & {\scriptsize T.Proc.} & {\scriptsize Límite} & {\scriptsize Ret.} & {\scriptsize Pen.} \\ \hline
  $j$ & $t_j$ & $d_j$ & $h_j$ & $p_j$ \\ \hline
  1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 45\\
  2 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 23\\
  3 & 4 & 14 & 4 & 4\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{subtable}%
%
\begin{subtable}{.48\linewidth}
{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  {\scriptsize Tarea} & {\scriptsize T.Proc.} & {\scriptsize Límite} & {\scriptsize Ret.} & {\scriptsize Pen.} \\ \hline
  $j$ & $t_j$ & $d_j$ & $h_j$ & $p_j$ \\ \hline
  29 & 42 & 175 & 32 & 23\\
  30 & 23 & 168 & 12 & 240\\
  31 & 17 & 35 & 123 & 23\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{subtable}%
\caption{JjjreA TABLE}\label{tab:1a}
\end{table}



AFTER The big BIG


\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `\centering`. Just put `\hfill` between the two tables.

Comment: @IanThompson That is the way to go. An answer?

Comment: Since you neither caption nor `\label` your subtables, do you even need them as subtables?  Why not just a `{tabular}\hfill{tabular}` approach?

Comment: @HarishKumar --- done.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `\centering`, try separating the two tables with a `\hfill`. Another possibility is to put one `\hfill` to the left, one in the middle and one to the right; this gives three spaces of equal size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\rule{4.5cm}{4.5cm} % replace with tabular
\hfill
\rule{4.5cm}{4.5cm} % replace with tabular
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}
\hfill
\rule{4.5cm}{4.5cm} % replace with tabular
\hfill
\rule{4.5cm}{4.5cm} % replace with tabular
\hfill\null
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: spacing]

Answer (score 0):

A *not so elegant* solution is to remove `\centering` and then `\raggedright` one and `\raggedleft` the other subtable:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
\raggedright
{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  {\scriptsize Tarea} & {\scriptsize T.Proc.} & {\scriptsize Límite} & {\scriptsize Ret.} & {\scriptsize Pen.} \\ \hline
  $j$ & $t_j$ & $d_j$ & $h_j$ & $p_j$ \\ \hline
  1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 45\\
  2 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 23\\
  3 & 4 & 14 & 4 & 4\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{subtable}%
%
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
\raggedleft
{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  {\scriptsize Tarea} & {\scriptsize T.Proc.} & {\scriptsize Límite} & {\scriptsize Ret.} & {\scriptsize Pen.} \\ \hline
  $j$ & $t_j$ & $d_j$ & $h_j$ & $p_j$ \\ \hline
  29 & 42 & 175 & 32 & 23\\
  30 & 23 & 168 & 12 & 240\\
  31 & 17 & 35 & 123 & 23\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{subtable}%
\caption{JjjreA TABLE}\label{tab:1a}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Or an `\hfill` between the two subtables.